# Facecolor changing edgecolor in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to remove the edge color in the plot of a cylinder where I have set an alpha and facecolors. However, if I also set the facecolors, I can still see the edge colors. If I remove the `alpha = 0.5` statement then the problem is resolved, however I need the alpha to be <1 . Here is an example:

[image]

You can still see the blue edgecolors even tough I have set the edgecolor to None.

This is the code where I use plot_surface()

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y,Z, edgecolor = "None", facecolors = col1, alpha = 0.5)
```

Yet the edge colors are still there? However, if I remove the facecolors statement inside plot_surface() then the edge colors are no longer there. Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.linalg import norm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection
import random
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
origin = np.array([0, 0, 0])
#axis and radius

p0 = np.array([0, 0, 0])
p1 = np.array([8, 8, 8])
R = 4
#vector in direction of axis
v = p1 - p0
#find magnitude of vector
mag = norm(v)
#unit vector in direction of axis
v = v / mag
#make some vector not in the same direction as v
not_v = np.array([1, 0, 0])
if (v == not_v).all():
    not_v = np.array([0, 1, 0])
#make vector perpendicular to v
n1 = np.cross(v, not_v)
#normalize n1
n1 /= norm(n1)
#make unit vector perpendicular to v and n1
n2 = np.cross(v, n1)
#surface ranges over t from 0 to length of axis and 0 to 2*pi
t = np.linspace(0, mag, 200)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
#use meshgrid to make 2d arrays
t, theta = np.meshgrid(t, theta)
#generate coordinates for surface
X, Y, Z = [p0[i] + v[i] * t + R * np.sin(theta) * n1[i] + R * np.cos(theta) *        n2[i] for i in [0, 1, 2]]
col1 = plt.cm.Blues(np.linspace(0,1,200)) # linear gradient along the t-axis
col1 = np.repeat(col1[np.newaxis,:, :], 100, axis=0) # expand over the theta-    axis


ax.plot_surface(X, Y,Z, edgecolor = None, facecolors = col1, alpha = 0.5)
#plot axis
ax.plot(*zip(p0, p1), color = 'red')
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)
ax.set_zlim(0, 10)
plt.axis('off')
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it have anything to do with you specifying `edgecolor = None` instead of `edgecolors`?

Comment: I tried both and neither worked

Comment: Is it a visual bug or are you plotting a decahedral prism inscribed by a circles?

Comment: I think a visual bug

Comment: Setting `linewidth=0` in `plot_surface()` seems to work with your example, although you can still see some edges, most likely because the transparent faces are slightly overlapping,

Comment: thanks @Bart it is working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `linewidth=0` in `plot_surface()` solves this problem:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, edgecolor=None, facecolors=col1, alpha=0.5, linewidth=0)
```

[image]

*p.s.: I didn't find this worth an answer, but per: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments), I added it as a quick answer so the question can be marked as solved*